# Background image does not extend to accessory view background in table view cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I'm using the code below to set a background under each cell in my table view. It works fine but there's a white space under the accessory view on the right side so the background does not cover this area. Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background.png"]];
}
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a custom cell. Please see [Apple's documentation about contentView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7).

To add subviews to a cell to customize it furthur please see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7). It also has a section on how to create custom cells from XIBs.

Comment: When you create a custom cell, you'd want to define your accessory view yourself too. OR alternatively, i think you should be able to set the background color of the accessoryView to what you are trying to set on contentView. Should work.